# cannot change the value of variable in if else inside foreach in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$this->db->where('scheme_id', 1);
                $query = $this->db->get('scheme_installment');
                $input = array();

                // Flag to check if the amount is available to add in customer installment table
                $hasMoreInstallments = TRUE;

                foreach($query->result_array() as $item) {

                    $input['scheme_installment_id'] = $item['scheme_installment_id'];
                    $input['customer_id'] = $insert_id;
                    $input['created_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $input['last_modified_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                    $data['down_payment'] -= $item['installment_price'];

                    if( $hasMoreInstallments && $data['down_payment'] >= 0) {

                        $input['paid_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                        $input['comment']   = $hasMoreInstallments.' : '.$data['down_payment'];

                        if($data['down_payment'] >= $item['installment_price'] ) {
                            $input['amount']    = $item['installment_price'];
                            $input['status'] = 'Paid';    
                        } else {
                            $input['amount']    = $data['down_payment'];
                            $hasMoreInstallments = FALSE;
                        }
                    }

                    $query = $this->db->insert('customer_installments', $input);
                }
                return $query;
```

Based on hasMoreInstallments (True/False) I want to insert the data. Here I'm not able to stop inserting as It is not modifying the value of hasMoreInstallments to FALSE. Every time loop runs, it consider hasMoreInstallments as TRUE, Though the records are printed on else block as well.

Comment: Have you debugged the code, especially the variables of interest $data['down_payment'] and $item['installment_price']?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem in not setting your variable to a value before subtracting from it.

From what I see the variable `$data['down_payment']` is never set to for example `0` like this:

```
$data['down_payment'] = 0;

// now we can subtract from it
$data['down_payment'] -= 5;
```

But if we don't assign a value to the variable and try subtracting values from it, it will have undefined values that may be breaking your script.

Comment: $data['down_payment'] contains value already. This is small snippet of whole code. Problem is $hasMoreInstallments = FALSE does not change it to FALSE. I don't want control inside if the $hasMoreInstallments is false

Comment: @TejramChafle can you show us an example table of your incoming data or  maybe echo the data as it comes in. It will be much easier to track the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It always inserts because

```
$query = $this->db->insert('customer_installments', $input);
```

is after the `if` condition

```
if($hasMoreInstallments && $data['down_payment'] >= 0)`{
  ...
}

//your insert is here
```

Comment: /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        : This function saves the customer record into the db
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function add_customer($data) {
$data['created_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$data['last_modified_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$query = $this->db->insert('customer', $data); $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
$this->db->where('scheme_id', 1); $query = $this->db->get('scheme_installment'); $input = array(); $hasMoreInstallments = TRUE;

Comment: I don't know how to be any more clear. The insert statement will ALWAY execute. It is not affected by the `if($hasMoreInstallments && $data['down_payment'] >= 0){` statement.

Comment: The code you gave in the comment has some serious flaws. But they are not exactly related to the question you ask.

Comment: I want to insert some data but not what is there inside the if. Say, there is  500 in $data['down_payment'] and I want to divide it into installments of 120, 150, 150, 150 as so on (till 12 months). This will not suffice since the amount is only 500. the remaining 80 after first 3 installments should be added where it is suppose to add next 150 hence set $hasMoreInstallments = FALSE and skip the code inside the outer if. I have other data too to insert, that's why the insert is outside the if. (Name of all the months, dates, decided fine, and decided installment amount).